# Golang multipart continuous response forwarding

Tags: python, http, go, flask

I have a server on flask-python which reads frames from camera and put them into multipart response as it do [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/video-streaming-in-web-browsers-with-opencv-flask-93a38846fe00) :

```
def get_feed():
    while True:
        ret, frame = server.get_frame()
        if not ret:
            try:
                frame = cv2.imread("data/misc/camera_error.jpg")
            except:
                frame = np.zeros(shape=(480, 640, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
        success, buffer = cv2.imencode(".jpg", 
                                       cv2.cvtColor(
                                             frame,
                                             cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                                       )
        buffer = buffer.tobytes()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + buffer + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return Response(get_feed(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

And I have golang-server which should accept GET requests, forward it to flask and forward a request to a client.

```
func api_camera_shot(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    resp, err := http.Get("http://" + *url here*)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(resp)            // debug error
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    buffer, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    for name, values := range resp.Header {
        // Loop over all values for the name.
        for _, value := range values {
            w.Header().Set(name, value)
        }
    }
    _, _ = w.Write(buffer)
}
```

But it stucks in the infinite loop and doesn't send anything to client. As far as I understand, `buffer, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)` cant't read whole body untill `while True` in flask still going and doesn't response.
How can I forward this continuous multipart request without stucking?

Comment: don't use ReadAll()!  resp.Body is type io.ReadCloser so there are many other options available

Comment: `io.Copy(w, resp.Body)`

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally, golang has proxy-functionality which I use now:

```
    origin, _ := url.Parse("http://" + *url-here*)

    director := func(req *http.Request) {
        req.Header.Add("X-Forwarded-Host", req.Host)
        req.Header.Add("X-Origin-Host", origin.Host)
        req.URL.Scheme = "http"
        req.URL.Host = origin.Host
        req.URL.Path = "/"
    }

    proxy := &httputil.ReverseProxy{Director: director}
    router.Get("/api/camera/*", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        proxy.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
```